# Excel - Lambda's helper MAP() function not valid

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

Ever since 2021 I've had acces to the newer lambda's helper functions among which was the [`MAP()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) function. All other helpers like `BYROW()`, `BYCOL()`, `SCAN()` and `REDUCE()` amongst others are working fine. Though the firstmentioned `MAP()` function is recognized by the Excel's auto-complete feature it will error out when applied. Let me show you in a few screenshots:

###### Auto-complete picking up on MAP():

[image]

###### Error "Invalid function" upon completion:

[image]

The strange part is that I can actually apply the formula through VBA:

```
Range("C1").Formula2 = "=MAP(A1:A2,LAMBDA(a,IF(a=1,a,a*2)))"
```

###### Resulting in:

[image]

###### Upon altering the formula I recieve the same error:

[image]

---

Up to now I have left this be, but I recently had a query where I'd have like to have used `MAP()`. Anyone seen this before/knows what the fix is?

---

Excel version: ms365 version 2211 build 15813.20002

---

**UPDATE 1:** Starting to get the feeling it has to do with local Dutch version of Excel since the following would also produce an error 1004 through VBA:

```
Range("C1").Formula2Local = "=MAP(A1:A2;LAMBDA(a;ALS(a=1;a;a*2)))"
```

**UPDATE 2:** Switched my Office display settings to English (United States) through File > Options > Language, let Excel update, and tried `MAP()`. It worked! Changing back to Dutch broke the function again though.

I guess the problem is a bug and I'll report it as such.

Comment: Great thanks for solving your own problem and providing feedback! I noticed you used semi-colons when entering the formula via the cell and comma's via VBA. So is it a language or delimiter setting issue?

Comment: Also, greetings from .ZA! Clearly you are dutch, why the South african flag?

Comment: Hey @ExcelEverything, yeah it appears to be something with the delimiter. And it's only with this particular function. Ticket has been sent. Also, yes I'm Dutch but my wife and extended family are South African.

Comment: Ah thought something like that. Do you have an excel solution to solve the issue of loadshedding? :.)

Comment: Haha, wife's parents live on the same grid as the nearby hospital. Near to no loadshedding. Wouldn't rely on Office to solve incompetence with DOE and Eskom.